# PHP MYSQL update table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using MYSQL and php to insert data into my sql.

I have two tables users and userrights.

I'm using checkbox to display rights on user edit page. when rights are de-selected or select i wont to update my userrights table.

```
CREATE TABLE userrights (
  userid int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  right_name varchar(50) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (userid,right_name)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;


INSERT INTO userrights (userid, right_name) VALUES
(1, 'add'),
(1, 'delete'),
(1, 'edit'),
(1, 'view'),
(2, 'add'),
(2, 'delete'),
(2, 'edit'),
(2, 'view');

CREATE TABLE users (
  id int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) collate latin1_general_ci default NULL,
  email varchar(100) collate latin1_general_ci default NULL,
  pass varchar(42) collate latin1_general_ci default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;

INSERT INTO users (id, name, email, pass) VALUES
(1, 'name', 'email@email.com', '5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99'),
(2, 'name name', 'email2@email.com', '1a1dc91c907325c69271ddf0c944bc72');
```

how do I do this?

Comment: Please clarify... are you asking how to write your queries to update permissions?... Or how to tie that functionality to a checkbox on your site (either using form submission, or Ajax)?

Comment: how add this functionality to site just by submitting the form

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem before.

The solution I came up with is truncate the table and reinsert all of the selected entries.

Comment: I did think of deleting all records and then re-enter records again

$sql = “INSERT INTO userrights ( 1, ‘add’ );”;
$sql .= “INSERT INTO userrights ( 1, ‘edit’ );”;
$sql .= “INSERT INTO userrights ( 1, ‘delete’ );”;

$result2 = mysql_query($sql);

Comment: @user1561124: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: @user1561124: Also, the use of PDO transaction in conjunction with prepared statements can give you a huge efficiency boost.

Comment: thank you for this information I have chnage my database to mysqli

Answer (score 0):

You get the data of the checkbox(true or false)

```
$rows = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userrights WHERE id = 'x' and right_name = 'y'"); // Please use insted of mysql_* PDO or MySQLi 
if ($rows > 0)
{
        if ($checkbox == false)
        {
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM userrights WHERE id = 'x' AND right_name = 'y'");
        }
}
else
{
// Recht nicht vorhanden --> if checkbox == true
      if ($checkbox == true)
      {
      mysql_query("INSERT INTO... VALUES ($id, $right_name)
      }
}
```

First you check if the user had the right. If yes you need to check if the right (data from checkbox) is set to false --> delete that row from the table.
If the user hadn't that right and the checkbox is true, you must insert that in your mysql_table.
The comments must be changed to and if-clause in your code.

Comment: if permission have already have been added and if i try select again they will be deleted and how do I add the permission and update user same time

Comment: the code above wasn't complete.
oh fuuuuuuu! I wrote something in German.... SOrry my fault. I changed the code abvoe!